# Is Alex Wilder still alive?

Tags: marvel, runaways

In Runaways v2 #24, we see the Gibborim “die”, and they end up in a white place with Alex. They don’t explain if they are technically “alive”, but it has something to do with Molly’s powers (because Alex can somehow communicate with her).

This isn’t explained in the series, so is there any explanation of this? Is there a follow-up, or did the writers just pretend it didn’t happen?

Comment: see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was assumed he died, but apparently he's making a return in the pages of *Avengers Undercover*. Specifically, he was resurrected by Daimon Hellstrom, so everything points to him having died in *Runaways* vol. 1 #24.